# Apollo GraphQL - resolver not being triggered

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo

I'm new to GraphQL. I started with the Javascript Apollo library and cannot get a resolver to fire. It's hard for me to tell when resolvers should be called, and what key I should put.

Here's my schema and resolvers:

```js
// The GraphQL schema in string form
const typeDefs = `
  type Query { user(id: ID!): User, posts: Post }
  type User  { id: ID!, created: Int, username: String, bio: String, status: String, avatar: String, posts: [Post] }
  type Post { id: ID!, created: Int, user_id: Int, text: String, object_set_id: Int, edited: Int, views: Int, upvotes: Int, downvotes: Int, Parent: Int }
`;

// The resolvers
const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        user: (parent, args, context, info) => {
            return users.find(user => user.id === Number(args.id));
        },
        // posts: () => posts,
    },
    Post: {
        id: (parent, args, context, info) => {
            console.log(posts.filter(post => post.user_id === Number(parent.id)))
            return posts.filter(post => post.user_id === Number(parent.id))
        }
    }
};
```

I want to specify a user by their user ID, then filter down to get all the posts that user has made (eventually with a time filter).

I've tried several things, but 'posts' under a user always comes up 'null'. What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: ... and tutorial you're following?

Comment: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/getting-started/

Then looking into resolver chains here: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/resolvers/

Comment: your, commented out, `Query.posts` resolver doesn't return a post list/array, then no chained `Post` resolver called (it should return one post, not required when Query.posts returns all post fields)

Comment: Please show us the value of your `users` array

Comment: That `Post.id` resolver makes no sense, it would need to return an `ID!` but appears to return an array of posts. Did you mean to write a `User.posts` resolver?

Comment: @Bergi that's exactly it! It needed to be a User: { posts } resolver.

Answer (score 1):

### User (Or more semantic:  userById) query

Your first query **works fine**.
You should also add some `data`(Otherwise you get an error `"message": "users is not defined",`).

[image]

Execute query:

```
query{
  user(id: 1){
    id
    username
  }
}
```

Basic code example:

```
const { ApolloServer, gql } = require("apollo-server");

const users = [
  {
    id: 1,
    username: "Kate Chopin"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    username: "Paul Auster"
  }
];

// The GraphQL schema in string form
const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    userById(id: ID!): User
  }
  type User {
    id: ID!
    username: String
  }
`;

// The resolvers
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    userById: (parent, args, context, info) => {
      return users.find((user) => user.id === Number(args.id));
    }
  }
};

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers
});

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(` Server ready at ${url}`);
});
```

### posts query (Or more semantic: `postById`):

About `posts` - your query is `posts` and no resolver match + looks like you do a little "salad" their.

It is better to follow this example (**Same idea** only **books/authors** instead of **posts/user**):
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/getting-started/

Next, read this **Resolver chains**: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/resolvers/#resolver-chains

Again `hello world` example

```
const posts = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Article One"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Article Two"
  }
];

const users = [
  {
    id: 1,
    username: "Kate Chopin",
    posts: posts
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    username: "Paul Auster"
  }
];

// The GraphQL schema in string form
const typeDefs = gql`
  type Query {
    userById(id: ID!): User
  }
  type User {
    id: ID!
    username: String
    posts: [Post]
  }
  type Post {
    id: ID!
    name: String
  }
`;

// The resolvers
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    userById: (parent, args, context, info) => {
      return users.find((user) => user.id === Number(args.id));
    }
  }
};

const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers
});

server.listen().then(({ url }) => {
  console.log(` Server ready at ${url}`);
});
```

Query:
[image]

Comment: This is great, but it looks like I can use a resolver like this:

    User: {
        posts: (parent, args, context, info) => {
            console.log(posts.filter(post => post.user_id === Number(parent.id)))
            return posts.filter(post => post.user_id === Number(parent.id))
        }
    }

Then the logic for the Users -> Posts isn't baked in unless requested.